# I want to give suggestions for Stack Overflow. Is it good to post them on Meta?

Tags: discussion, meta

I have some suggestions for improving of Stack Overflow, but I don't know if there is any other place where I can give my suggestions.

Should I post them here?

Comment: stackoverflow developer guys please debug the bugs in authentication process as i have a hard time to authenticate mainly creating career profile.

Comment: Have a read of [How to participate in meta and not die trying](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44189/194906). I found it pertinent when I'd made a suggestion that wasn't very well received. (MSO is usually quite conservative and sometimes interprets suggestions for change as criticism of something that is loved.)

Comment: @Freedom **don't** suggest edits to draw attention for the question. This was a minor edit. And don't add *to draw more attention to your question* in edit summery.

Comment: @hims056 I'm not sure what extra attention *was* required, it's already been answered by a StackExchange community manager *and* that answer has been accepted. Bumping for more attention at this point is just...weird.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, this is the right place.

Usually you'll want to tag your suggestions with [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), but it depends somewhat on what they are. [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is fine for posts that are proposing new site features or changes to how existing site features work. But if you're just bringing up site policy changes, for example, [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) would be more appropriate.

Comment: And if you do make it a feature request, don't be shocked if you receive a couple of downvotes @Ðeepak. This is still the right place, but the downvotes [might indicate disagreement](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) with your proposal.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep it in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: The new location for posting Stack Overflow feature requests is at https://meta.stackoverflow.com (not https://meta.stackexchange.com).

**Details:** [Operation 'Split, All The Metas!' Shall Commence On April 16, 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014)

Comment: There's a bit of nuance here - while the SO featurebase has diverged somewhat - the 'core' platform is still the same, so many 'SO' questions are on topic here. I'd say maybe 80-90% of questions of 'mechanics' of the site are common, though naturally questions of governance and culture belong on the appropriate per site meta

Comment: Also, FYI, back when this question was originally posted, this site was hosted on the domain meta.stackoverflow.com. Then, a year later, it was moved to meta.stackexchange.com, and a brand new per-site meta was established on the former domain.