# Make it easier to determine the question's programming-language on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, visibility

Often, I find it difficult to quickly identify the language I'm looking at. Sometimes it is not obvious, and I need to scroll down or look in the tags.  I feel like it should be specified right at the top.

[image]

Comment: Did you ask about this on Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: @RandomPerson - There was a [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180780/i-want-to-give-suggestions-for-stack-overflow-is-it-good-to-post-them-on-meta) that feature requests for stackoverflow should be submitted in Meta.

Comment: @RandomPerson - Thank you. I did not realize there was a https://meta.stackoverflow.com. Sorry, I posted this in the wrong community.

Comment: The question which you linked in the first comment is very old and things have changed since then: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228888/

Comment: If you look at the [ToS](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service), it says that you grant SE an irrevocable right to display anything you post. If the "delete" button doesn't work, you can't delete it. Best you can do is contact SE to have your name removed from it.

Comment: I answered this because, even though it mentions Stack Overflow, it actually applies to all the programming sites on the network (e.g. [softwareengineering.se], [codegolf.se]). I do also understand the closure.

Answer (score 11):

[image: The language tag is at the very beginning of the page .]

Comment: For longer tags and sufficiently many tabs open in the browser (and possibly other factors), it is cut off. For instance, [this JavaScript one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77258348/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-leave-unimportant-promises-unresolved) only shows "jav" (in a particular tab/browser/system configuration). A third way is hovering the mouse cursor (or the equivalent) over the tab. This will display the full text.

Answer (score 0):

What if there was a little icon in the top right.  The icon would help the user quickly identify (with even just peripheral vision) what the concerning language is.

Example 1, I am using the common Java image.
[image]

Example 2, I am using the C# logo from wikipedia.org.
[image]

Comment: We actually have something similar coming as a result of the Collectives feature: see, for example, [PHP questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139/5223757). (Though it's on the top right, not the top-left as in your example.) I, personally, find this a tad annoying, but it's good to see that _some_ people would find it useful – almost as though Stack Overflow's design people know what they're doing!

Comment: This seems like something that you could write a userscript for if you wanted. Fetch the list of tags, have some list of tags to language logos mapping, and then add the logo as an element before the title.

Comment: If you do, make sure to publish it on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com)! (The one SE site without a magic comment link…)

Comment: @cocomac - Great idea... Users could choose if they liked it or not.  Maybe can be added to an existing tool like https://github.com/riccardoFasan/stack-overflow-tweaks-tool